# Get the value after = in a given string in Powershell using Regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string as given below

```
$string1 = "PTSKKV = 3.5  PTSPK = 4.6"
```

I tried to write a regular expression for getting the value 3.5 if i provide "PTSKKV" and 4.6 if i provide "PTSPK" as given below

```
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($string1 , "(?<=PTSKKV\s*=\s*)[^\s]+").Value
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($string1 , "(?<=PTSPK\s*=\s*)[^\s]+").Value
```

But unfortunalely iam getting null value from above command.What went wrong for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your actual goal is, but if you want to be able to look up the value of a particular key in that string, I'd probably use an entirely different approach.

Replace the whitespace between key/value pairs with line-feeds, then convert the string to a hashtable. After that you can simply access each value by its respective key:

```
PS C:\> $s = "PTSKKV = 3.5  PTSPK = 4.6"
PS C:\> $h = ($s -replace '\s\s+',"`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
PS C:\> $h

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PTSPK                          4.6
PTSKKV                         3.5


PS C:\> $v = 'PTSPK'
PS C:\> $h[$v]
4.6
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: what should i do if i have another string like 
$s= "PTS KKV = 3.5 PTS PK = 4.6"

Comment: @user1654136 That depends on the structure of the string. How are the `key = value` pairs separated from each other? By multiple spaces? A single space? A tab? Are the keys always letters and the values always decimal numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Some languages won't support `*`,`+`,`?` in look-behinds. So your regex would be,

```
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($string1 , "(?<=PTSKKV\s=\s)[^\s]+").Value
[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($string1 , "(?<=PTSPK\s=\s)[^\s]+").Value
```

**EXplanation:**

- `(?<=PTSKKV\s=\s)` Lookbehind sets the matching marker just after to the string `PTSKKV =`
- `[^\s]+` Matches one or more non space characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if ($subject -cmatch '(?<=PTSKKV = )\S+') {
    $result = $matches[0]
}
```

For the other one, just replace the `PTSKKV` with `PTSPK`.

**Option 2: Retrieve Both in a Single Pass**

```
if ($subject -cmatch 'PTSKKV = (\S+)\s*PTSPK = (\S+)') {
    $ptskkv = $matches[1]
    $ptspk = $matches[2]
}
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=PTSKKV = )` asserts that what precedes is `PTSKKV`
- `\S+` matches any non-whitespace characters

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will match the value until the first whitespace character.
Just replace the PTSKKV with the name of the value you search for.

```
(?<=PTSKKV[\s]*?=[\s]*?)[^\s]+
```